# Multiple PHP pages, one MySQL connection info page?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I am trying to include a PHP page into another PHP page.

I find it annoying that I have to change the connection info on every page when I upload it to the web host all over agin when I like to edit.

I was wondering if there was a way to include a page that way so I can keep the connection info in one file for all pages.

```
$username = "a";
$password = "a";
$hostname = "a.com"; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username , $password, 'a');
```

For example:

- 1.php
- 2.php
- 3.php  <-- this page will hold the info and be include in to pages 1 and 2

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: should i delete it ? ([duplicate])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create to files auth.php and config.php

In config.php specify your variables

```
//config.php
    $username = "a";
    $password = "a";
    $hostname = "a.com";
```

Include your config file in auth.php

```
//auth.php
include('config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username , $password, 'a');
```

Use different config.php file on your local and web servers.:)

Answer (score 1):

Use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include other files.

1.php:

```
<?php

$username = "a";
$password = "a";
$hostname = "a.com"; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username , $password, 'a');
```

2.php:

```
<?php

include '1.php';
// Rest of your code
```

3.php:

```
<?php

include '1.php';
// Rest of your code
```

Comment: thx i did see this example in 3wschool but it was in to html and it didnt work for me when i tryed it, but i tryed it agin now seem to work not sure why but got what i needed so :)

Answer (score 0):

You could read a bit on AJAX .. that way you could stay on the same page sending info asynchronously